# Is there a CakePHP isAuthorized() for simple allow()/deny()?

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication

I have an app in which I'm using allow()/deny() for most of the access control, and I would like to be able to check in beforeFilter() if the user is authorized or not.  If I were using controller or one of the other auth methods, I could use isAuthorized(), but that doesn't work for allow/deny - I want it to return true if a user isn't logged in but they're on a publicly accessible page.

To maybe take a step back and allow for other solutions: I have my app set up using subdomains (user.example.com), and if they aren't using a subdomain, I want to return 404 for the non-frontend pages, and only allow them to access them via a user subdomain.

Is there a better way to do this - perhaps by adding controller authorization?  I still would run into the issue of needing to know whether or not they are authorized.  Is there a way to alter what the Auth component does when authorization fails?  I want it to return 404, but only on certain conditions (specifically, the user is not accessing the site via a subdomain).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

allow() and deny() only refers to the ability to access a url without being logged in. The isAuthorized callback in the controller is better suited for permissions of users that already passed through the login form.

Please check this tutorial for clarification: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html

Comment: Yeah, that's what I had gathered...I basically want a way to tell if a user is allow()ed to access a page, that is, if the page they're on is a publicly accessible page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Blackhole](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1307/blackHole-object-controller-string-error) to return 404 errors. The rest of the question I don't totally understand. You use Auth but a custom ACL?

Comment: Thanks for the blackHole link - that makes things easier.  And I'm not really using an ACL (yet) - just some manual permissions checking/redirection.